# Unable to install tortoisehg on Linux RHEL 7.4

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm a long-time user of tortoisehg own Windows 7, but new to RedHat Linux. 
I have python 2.7.5 installed on my Linux RHEL 7.4 virtual machine.
I installed hg (version 4.0-rc) by following these directions:
   https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download#Linux_.28.rpm.29
(I had to change 'baseurl=https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/centos$releasever' to 'baseurl=https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/centos7')

Then I downloaded and installed tortoisehg-4.2.2-1.fc27.noarch.rpm from:
   https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/tortoisehg/4.2.2/1.fc27/noarch/tortoisehg-4.2.2-1.fc27.noarch.rpm

And tortoisehg-nautilus-4.2.2-1.fc27.noarch.rpm from:
   https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/tortoisehg/4.2.2/1.fc27/noarch/tortoisehg-nautilus-4.2.2-1.fc27.noarch.rpm

hg seems to work, but when I try to start thg, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/thg", line 97, in 
      sys.exit(tortoisehg.hgqt.run.dispatch(argv))
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 152, in **getattribute**
      self._load()
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 100, in _load
      mod = _hgextimport(_import, head, globals, locals, None, level)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 53, in _hgextimport
      return importfunc(name, globals, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tortoisehg/hgqt/run.py", line 400, in 
      _('repository root directory or symbolic path name')),
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tortoisehg/util/i18n.py", line 76, in agettext
      return hglib.fromunicode(u)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 152, in **getattribute**
      self._load()
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 100, in _load
      mod = _hgextimport(_import, head, globals, locals, None, level)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 53, in _hgextimport
      return importfunc(name, globals, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tortoisehg/util/hglib.py", line 592, in 
      loadui = uimod.ui.load
  AttributeError: type object 'ui' has no attribute 'load'

I have no idea how to proceed. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Yuya N.  at [Unable to install thg on RHEL 7.4 Linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20200706170659/https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/4956/unable-to-install-thg-on-rhel-74-linux) I was able to get thg working.
The problem was the the major.minor versions of hg and and tortoisehg must match.
I uninstalled tortoisehg-4.2.2-1 and installed tortoisehg-4.0.1 and thg now works.